# Express.js App Not Serving Static Asset

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Unsure why I keep getting this: 
localhost GET http://localhost:3000/public/bundle.js 404 (Not Found) 
I've tried to change output of the webpack.config files, routes in my server and my index.html bundle file location. Nothing seems to be changing the error I keep getting. Can anyone help?

Index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const expressMiddleware = (app) => {
 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyparser.json());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/public')));
}

module.exports = expressMiddleware;
```

Webpack.config.js

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./frontend/app.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'/frontend/public'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', `react`]
        }
      },
       {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
  }
};
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>

 <body>
     <div id="app"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src='/public/bundle.js'></script>
 </body>
<html/>
```

Server.js

```js
//Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Files
const expressMiddleware = require('./middleware/index.js');

//Middleware
expressMiddleware(app);

// Frontend Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Running on 3000'));

//Export App
module.exports = app;
```

Middleware.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const expressMiddleware = (app) => {
 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyparser.json());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/public')));
}

module.exports = expressMiddleware;
```

Directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ1la.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've set your Express App to serve static files from the Public folder.

Therefore, when importing your front-end `bundle.js` file in `Index.html`, your src should be set to `/bundle.js`, there's no need to include `/public` since Express is already serving assets from that directory.

Hope that helps, I don't really see why your asset shouldn't load otherwise...

More info: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your React app :)